# Converting HeapSort and ShellSort from C to Pascal

Tags: c, pascal, heapsort, shellsort

I have a problem with two kinds of sorts — Heap and Shell. I have some code in C and I need to try using the same commands (like when I use in C a 'for-loop', I want to use a 'for-loop' for Pascal as well) in the bodies of the procedures. I try, but the sorts don't work like they do in C. In C, all is working great with arrays of size 40000.

Code for ShellSort in C where parameter 'n' is a size of array:

```
    shellSort(int n){
      int shift,pom,j,i;
      shift = n/2;
      while(shifta>0){
        for (i = shift; i < n; i += 1){
            pom=arr[i];
            j=i;
            while((j>=shift) && (arr[j-shift]>pom)){
                arr[j] = arr[j - shift]; 
                j=j-shift;
            }
            arr[j]=pom;
        }
        shift= shift / 2;
      }
   }
```

Declaration in Pascal

```
  arr :array[0..22] of integer;       
  size:integer =23;
```

Code in Pascal with the same parameters:

```
procedure ShellSort(n:integer); 
Var
 shift , pom : Integer;
Begin
  shift:=n div 2 ; 
  While shift>0 Do
    Begin
      For i:=shift to n Do
        Begin
          pom:=arr[i];
          j:=i;
          While (j>=shift) and (arr[j-shift]>pom) Do
            Begin
              arr[j]:=arr[j-shift];
              j:= j-shift
            End;
            arr[j]:=pom;
        End;
        shift:=shift div 2;
    End;
End;
```

Code for Heap sort in C:

```
heapSort() {
    int N = size;
    int k;
    int pom;
    for (k = N / 2; k > 0; k--) {
        downHeap(k, N);
    }
    do {
        pom = arr[0];
        arr[0] = arr[N - 1];
        arr[N - 1] =  pom;
        N = N - 1;
        downHeap(1, N);
    } while (N > 1);

}

downHeap(int k, int N) {
    int T = arr[k - 1];
    while (k <= N / 2) {
        int j = k + k;

        if ((j < N) && (arr[j - 1] < arr[j])) {
            j++;
        }
        if (T >= arr[j - 1]) {
            break;
        } else {
            arr[k - 1] = arr[j - 1];
            k = j;
        }
    }
    arr[k - 1] = T;
}
```

Code for Heap sort in Pascal:

```
procedure downHeap(k:integer;N:integer);
var
  T:integer;
begin
  T:=arr[k-1];
  while(k<= (N div 2)) do
    begin
      j:=k+k;
      if ((j<N) and (arr[j-1]<arr[j])) then
        begin
          j:=j+1;
        end;
      if (T>=arr[j-1]) then
        begin
          exit;
        end
      else
        begin
          arr[k-1]:=arr[j-1];
          k:=j;
        end;
    end;
    arr[k-1]:=T;
end;

procedure heapSort;
var
  n, pom:integer;
begin
  n:=size;
  for i:=n div 2 downto 1 do
    begin
      downHeap(i,n);
    end;
  repeat
    begin
      pom:=arr[0];
      arr[0]:=arr[n-1];
      arr[n-1]:=pom;
      n:=n-1;
      downHeap(1,n);
   end;
  until n>1;
end;
```

Output from Pascal:

```
Unsorted array
10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 3 2 1 0 15 15 15 15 14 18 99 1 19 95 95

BubbleSort
0 1 1 2 3 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 14 15 15 15 15 18 19 95 95 99

HeapSort
95 95 15 18 95 15 15 15 18 19 95 0 5 4 15 3 14 7 3 1 2 1 99

ShellSort
0 0 1 1 2 3 3 4 5 7 14 15 15 15 15 15 18 18 19 95 95 95 95

Expected
0 1 1 2 3 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 14 15 15 15 15 18 19 95 95 99
```

I am really depressed.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It's unusual to see a question related to Pascal.  You might care to read [Why Pascal is not my favorite programming language](https://www.lysator.liu.se/c/bwk-on-pascal.html). Much of what is said there remains true, though I've no doubt that there have been some changes in Pascal since that was written (circa 1981). Your C code is not an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))
(or MRE or whatever name SO now uses) or an SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)). Your Pascal is also incomplete.

Comment: ... and don't post pictures of text. Post text as text.

Comment: In the Shell sort, the C loop is `for (i = shift; i < n; i += 1){` and the Pascal loop is `For i:=shift to n Do`.  The Pascal loop is looping once to often; it needs to be `For i := shift to n-1 Do` (assuming expressions are allowed in loop limits — if not, you need an extra variable `var ub: integer;` and `ub := n - 1;` and then `For i := shift to ub Do` or thereabouts.  The C `for` loop is much more general than the Pascal `for` loop.

Comment: In the Heap sort, the C loop is `do { … } while (N > 1);` and you've translated that to `repeat … until n > 1;`.  The terminating condition is wrong; `until` is equivalent to `while not`, so you need `repeat … until n <= 1;`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler oh man, thank you so much, it is working great now. Pascal is Spanish village (i don't know if this phrase using in your country) for me. Again, thank you.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I have one more question for you, do you know how to measure a using virtual memory in pascal? Or another kind of memory.

Comment: I've no idea about how to measure the virtual memory used by Pascal programs other than the general command line tools such as `ps` or `top`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sup>*Transferring comments into an answer.*</sup>

In the Shell sort, the C loop is:

```
for (i = shift; i < n; i += 1){
```

and the Pascal loop is

```
For i:=shift to n Do
```

The Pascal loop is looping once too often; it needs to be:

```
For i := shift to n-1 Do
```

assuming expressions are allowed in loop limits — if not, you need an extra variable, roughly like this:

```
var ub: integer;
ub := n - 1;

For i := shift to ub Do
```

The C for loop is much more general and flexible than the Pascal for loop.

In the Heap sort, the C loop is:

```
do { … } while (N > 1);
```

and you've translated that to

```
repeat … until n > 1;
```

The terminating condition is wrong; `until` is equivalent to `while not`, so you need:

```
repeat … until n <= 1;
```

I've by no means scrutinized the whole of the Pascal code — and I have no Pascal compiler to test with — so there could be other issues to be resolved still, but these two should get you going.  (Make sure you've checked all the occurrences of `for` and `repeat … until` for the problems outlined here.)